# what is query string of Ebay.com to search product?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ebay-api

I am developing an application in which I need to search item on `ebay.com` with the help of bar code.

Can some one guide me how to search product in `ebay.com` by query string like we normally do in google.com `http://www.google.com/search?q=bar code`?

Comment: [Ebay advanced search](http://shop.ebay.com/ebayadvsearch/?_skipfnorm=1&rt=nc) has no field for barcode. Also, what language/technology are you talking about?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning, i am developing application for iphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of [complete eBay API](https://github.com/roopeshvaddepally/python-ebay/wiki/List-of-eBay-APIs) (unofficial) and official one is [here](http://developer.ebay.com/support/docs/).

To cut the long story short, if you need to query ebay by a keyword, say "ipod". You need to use [findItemsByKeywords](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/finditemsbykeywords.html#Samples) API operation in [Finding API](http://developer.ebay.com/products/finding/):

The REST-like query will be something like this:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.11.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=YourAppId&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=ipod&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2
```

Where you need to specify: APPNAME. Which you will get after registering on [eBay developer program here](https://developer.ebay.com/Join/default.aspx)

If you are building a phone app, you need to use [redlaser API](http://redlaser.com/sdk/) (it's an eBay company)

Comment: i am getting you, but i just need to make search with bar code.

Comment: ok, but what would you search? ebay does not have a catalog or items which will directly match with the bar code id. You need some external API which will translate that bar code id to the product key word, then search for that keyword on ebay api.

Comment: hmmm ok, my application relevant to parlor, so i need to compare prices online...

Comment: The `RedLaser` feature list for their free app includes price comparisons and such, so I think you'll find the SDK does what you need.